# How to create an Object or Field which can be updated using a rich text editor and pulled into VFP

Tags: apex, visualforce, richtextarea

I am quite new to Salesforce, and this question may have already been asked but I could not find it so I apologise ahead of time if this is a duplicate.

I wish to be able to create or implement an Object or field or ability to have a rich text editor where our Staff can easily update this data and it can be pulled into our visual force page using an Apex Class.

To be more specific we want to have a Terms and Conditions which can easily be managed on the backend using a Rich Text Editor. It should be straight forward but I can't seem to figure it out or find it. Thank you very much for any assistance on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create or use an existing standard or custom object as the field provides the rich text ability. So create a field **Sample_TermsConditions__c** with Text Area (Rich) type in an object, let's say **XYZ** object. Place this field in the XYZ's page layout for users with that field permission to fill in and edit. Following is the sample code to render the rich text data in the visualforce page.

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="XYZ__c" >
    <apex:pageblock title="Terms & Conditions">
        <apex:pageblockSection >
            <apex:outputField value="{!XYZ__c.Sample_TermsConditions__c}"  />
        </apex:pageblockSection>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:page>
```

I think this meets your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom object with a field and a visualforce page to accomplish your task.
1.Create a custom object with field type 'TextArea(rich)'
2.Code VF page showing that field

- have a standardcontroller set on this vfpage to the custom object created in the first step.
- Have a commandbutton on the vf page to save the field value using the standard save method.

Please have a read through of [this](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_pages_developers_guide.pdf) doc